# number figures by order of appearence in text

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

Because of the shape of the involved figures and the way in which I can intuitively group them (and also to save space), I want the figures to appear in a different order than they are referenced in the text. I would prefer the figure numbers to be numbered after the order of appearance of their first reference in the text. Something like:

```
In Fig. 1 we show this, while in Fig. 2 we show that and Fig. 3 shows something else again.
[Figure 1] [Figure 3]
[Figure 2 (does not fit well with the other two)]
```

How can this be done in LaTeX. It's not a big amount of figures, so a manual option would be acceptable, though not preferable.

Comment: Shall the figure order really be changed or is it the change of numbering order only?

Comment: I need this to make the text read more naturally, while the figures fit better on the page. The figures are in their proper position, I just want the numbering to be in order of reference in the text, not the figure order.

Comment: @Octaviour: I find this confusing. I don't expect some figure numbered 5 (say) to appear before number 1, just because you refer to '5' first. This will confuse readers, in my point of view.

Comment: Using floats, your text will be much easier to read. You save space, pictures are placed with respect to the space available and they are numbered in order and referenced according to that order. People have done it for years, because they saw it was good.

Comment: In other words: You write your text, you give the images in the order in which you need them. LaTeX does the rest. And does it well.

Comment: Normally I would agree, but in this case the number of pages is limited and the 2nd, 4th and 5th figure of the paper just happen to be highly correlated to each other. Therefore these group really well into subfigures. This does however make the numbering feel strange. I'm aware that this is not an ideal solution, but I do feel this one is the least bad.

Comment: Put all of them in *one* figure environment, give them all *one* caption (they are related, right?) and use `subfigure` (package `subcaption`) to give each figure an additional specific caption.

Comment: That might indeed be a nice solution in this situation. For the sake of other people looking for something similar, I would still be interested in a way to actually change the figure numbers though.